# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured and TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable

Tags: python, django, django-apps

I have a very annoying problem. There are errors in the project I am creating:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf
>   'My_Site.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see
>   valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a
>   circular import.`and`TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable

views.py:

```py
class UserRegisterView(View):

    def get(self, request):
        form = UserCreationFormv2()
        return render(request, "registrationReg.html", {'form': form})`

    def post(self, request):
        form = UserCreationFormv2(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            login(request, user, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
            UpdateUser.objects.create(user=user)
        else:
        return render(request, "main.html")
```

urls.py:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from MySite.views import OrganizationRegisterView, UserRegisterView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', OrganizationRegisterView.as_view(), name='Organizators Registration'),
    path('/user', UserRegisterView.as_view(), name='Regular User Registration')
    ]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have anything in urls.py in project dir, not just in app dir? same level where is settings.py

Comment: yes, urls.py is in the same dir as settings.py, furthermore i run it few times, and after 2 or 3 changes, it just stop working. I return last changes from git, but i need that ViewClass

Comment: if views.py is in urls.py dir too why not just: from .views import Organizaztion...

Comment: views are in app dir, there is probably mistake in code